# Django, no module named 'polls' - Django reusable apps

Tags: python, django

I am at the end of the getting started of the Django project, I built the package as described in the [Advanced tutorial: How to write reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/reusable-apps/).
I got a tar.gz file that I installed **not** in a virtual environment using the command `python.exe -m pip install --user C:\Users\[PRIVACY AMEND]\Documents\python\mysite\django-polls\dist\django-polls-0.1.tar.gz`. The module is installed as shown in the output of `python.exe -m pip list` below.

```
Package      Version   
------------ -------   
asgiref      3.5.2  
Django       4.1.1  
django-polls 0.1  
lxml         4.9.1  
sqlparse     0.4.2  
tzdata       2022.2
```

But when I migrate, I get the error no module named polls...
I have done all steps of the tutorial on Windows and Debian (on WSL), using explicitly python.exe -m pip when interacting with pip, checked the logs for any other error, and checked the PYTHONPATH and where the package is installed given by `python.exe -m pip show django-polls`, the output is just below.

```
Name: django-polls  
Version: 0.1  
Summary: A Django app to conduct web-based polls.  
Home-page: https://www.example.com/  
Author: Your Name  
Author-email: yourname@example.com  
License: BSD-3-Clause  # Example license  
Location: c:\users\[PRIVACY AMEND]\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages  
Requires: Django  
Required-by:
```

Does anyone have a hint ?

Comment: Did you add `django-polls` to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, as below
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
]
And, I also included the polls' routes into the urls.py file of the django project. I included the function include from drjango.urls
urlpatterns = [
    path( 'polls/', include('polls.urls') ),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]